# How can I measure the **height** of a single word, but **inside** `\newcommand` which means the text may change every time

Tags: macros, height

How can I measure the **height** of a single word, but **inside** `\newcommand` which means the text may change every time.

Using the code in [How to 'translate' a numerical value into a word with \newcommand?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385946/how-to-translate-a-numerical-value-into-a-word-with-newcommand) (with many thanks to Werner) and I modified to:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\Calendar}[3]{%
\noindent
\ifcase #1\or% 0
January\or % 1
February\or % 2
March\or % 3
April\or % 4
May\or % 5
June\or % 6
July\or % 7
August\or % 8
September\or % 9
October\or % 10
November\or % 11
December% 12
\fi
\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#2%
\ifcase #2\or% 0
st\or % 1
nd\or % 2
rd\or % 3
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
st\or % 21
nd\or % 22
rd\or % 23
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
st% 31
\fi}}
\\
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#3}}%
\vspace{0.4em}
}

\begin{document}

\Calendar{2}{2}{1989}

\Calendar{1}{31}{1990}

\Calendar{3}{23}{1991}

\end{document}
```

It outputs the following:

[image]

I would like to measure the **height** of the first argument (#1, which is the month) so I can draw a box around the month **only** that **exactly** matches its height, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Factor the macro into several separate macros (this macro can be split into two extra macros), then you can easily use `\settowidth ` (look it up) on say `\Month{#1} `

Comment: What will you do with this width?

Comment: If the `width` is to be queried, why is this tagged with [tag:height]?

Comment: In the title an the first sentence you are asking for the **width** in the last sentence and the tags you are asking for the **height**. That makes is somehow unclear. IMHO measuring the height does not make any sense here. So my answer is about the width. Nevertheless, you can get the height using `\settoheight` and `\settodepth` if you need it.

Comment: Sorry, my question is unclear indeed. But I would like to make a box that matches the content **to the pixel**

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to measure the width. You can use either a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\Calendar}[3]{%
\noindent
\ifcase #1\or% 0
January\or % 1
February\or % 2
March\or % 3
April\or % 4
May\or % 5
June\or % 6
July\or % 7
August\or % 8
September\or % 9
October\or % 10
November\or % 11
December% 12
\fi
\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#2%
\ifcase #2\or% 0
st\or % 1
nd\or % 2
rd\or % 3
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
st\or % 21
nd\or % 22
rd\or % 23
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
st% 31
\fi}}
\\
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#3}}%
\vspace{0.4em}
}

\begin{document}

\Calendar{2}{2}{1989}

\Calendar{1}{31}{1990}

\Calendar{3}{23}{1991}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabular]

or `tabular` inside `\fbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\Calendar}[3]{%
  \noindent
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
\ifcase #1\or% 0
January\or % 1
February\or % 2
March\or % 3
April\or % 4
May\or % 5
June\or % 6
July\or % 7
August\or % 8
September\or % 9
October\or % 10
November\or % 11
December% 12
\fi
\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#2%
\ifcase #2\or% 0
st\or % 1
nd\or % 2
rd\or % 3
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
st\or % 21
nd\or % 22
rd\or % 23
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
st% 31
\fi}}
\\
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#3}}\\
  \end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\Calendar{2}{2}{1989}

\Calendar{1}{31}{1990}

\Calendar{3}{23}{1991}

\end{document}
```

[image: \fbox + tabular]

or `varwidth` inside `\fbox` to make a box around it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\Calendar}[3]{%
  \noindent
  \fbox{\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}\raggedright
\ifcase #1\or% 0
January\or % 1
February\or % 2
March\or % 3
April\or % 4
May\or % 5
June\or % 6
July\or % 7
August\or % 8
September\or % 9
October\or % 10
November\or % 11
December% 12
\fi
\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#2%
\ifcase #2\or% 0
st\or % 1
nd\or % 2
rd\or % 3
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
st\or % 21
nd\or % 22
rd\or % 23
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
st% 31
\fi}}
\\
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#3}}\\
  \end{varwidth}}%
}

\begin{document}

\Calendar{2}{2}{1989}

\Calendar{1}{31}{1990}

\Calendar{3}{23}{1991}

\end{document}
```

[image: varwidth + \fbox]

This does also work for very short month like May, where the yer could be wider than the name of the month. Nevertheless, if you like to measure, use `\settowidth` or `\widthof`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}% for \widthof


\newcommand*{\Month}[1]{%
  \ifcase #1\or% 0
  January\or % 1
  February\or % 2
  March\or % 3
  April\or % 4
  May\or % 5
  June\or % 6
  July\or % 7
  August\or % 8
  September\or % 9
  October\or % 10
  November\or % 11
  December% 12
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\Calendar}[3]{%
  \noindent
  \fbox{\begin{minipage}{\widthof{\Month{#1}}}\raggedright
    \Month{#1}\\
\textcolor{blue}{\textit{#2%
\ifcase #2\or% 0
st\or % 1
nd\or % 2
rd\or % 3
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
st\or % 21
nd\or % 22
rd\or % 23
th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or th\or % 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30
st% 31
\fi}}
\\
\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#3}}\\
  \end{minipage}}%
}

\begin{document}

\Calendar{2}{2}{1989}

\Calendar{1}{31}{1990}

\Calendar{5}{23}{1991}% Problem!!!

\end{document}
```

[image: measure with May problem]

BTW: For more nice boxes see [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).